# Dead keys Microsoft typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, dead-key

I made a virtual keyboard in typescript that prints the event.key in the inputfield. It has to be compatible with different input method languages, like Dutch and French. These keyboards have Dead keys, for example the `.

Now this works fine for Chrome and Firefox but for Microsoft (Edge and Internet Explorer) it won't work.

I think this is because in Chrome the event.key is 'Dead' and it functions accordingly. In Edge and IE the event.key is 'Unidentified' so it doesn't print the dead key when paired with spacebar.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

see https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS

tip: use the textInput method for east Asian languages and the MS IME.